# django: Extending user model using one-to-one: how to save() Profile model's fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-users, django-signals

I have a basic Django application, wherein along with the User model I have extended the Profile model using **One-to-one field**.

Models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True)
  profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='customer_profile_images/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Profile Picture")
  phone_number = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=10)

  # no need for following two methods
  # def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # if created:
        # Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

  # post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)

  def __str__(self):
     return f'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}'
```

In **admin.py** I have registered the Profile model as follow:

```
from myapp import Profile


class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('user', 'phone_number')

admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

And a Profile model is being successfully created within the User model.

And at the time of creating a new account for a user **in views.py**

```
class CustomerSignUpView(View):
def post(self, request):
    name_r = request.POST.get('customer_username')
    password_r = request.POST.get('customer_password')
    email_r = request.POST.get('customer_email')
    contact_number_r = request.POST.get('customer_contact_number')
    profile_picture_r = request.FILES['customer_profile_picture']

     # this is how i am saving contact number, profile picture for Profile model.

    if checkemail(email_r):
        c = User.objects.create_user(username=name_r, password=password_r, email=email_r)
        c.save()

        # add the following code
        p = Profile(user=c, phone_number=contact_number_r, profile_picture=profile_picture_r)
        p.save()       

        return render(request, 'catalog/customer_login.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'catalog/customer_signup.html')

def get(self, request):
    return render(request, 'catalog/customer_signup.html')
```

However, while creating a new user account in sign up page, i encounter the following error:

[image: error]

**I don't understand how to save those newly created fields of Profile model using save() method.**

**UPDATE: Solution found-**

In views.py, this is how I am saving fields inside Profile model

```
     p = Profile(user=c, phone_number=contact_number_r, profile_picture=profile_picture_r)
     p.save()
```

**And now, whenever I sign up a new user, the username, profile picture and phone number get added in the Profile model as well, and even during deleting/updating profile details the changes are reflected in both User and Profile Model**

Following link is useful for my project requirements:

http://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/one_to_one.html

Comment: I just want to know before writing the answer, are you customizing the admin? If not then you don't need model admin. And also use `create_or_update_user_profile` only or use `create_user_profile` and `save_user_profile`

Comment: I am customizing the admin panel for many other models that I have created, and I have tried your solution..right now I just have a create_or_update_usere_profile() method, yet the error persists

Comment: I think you can just create dummy userprofile for all existing user objects.

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html                        It’s a very simplest explanation to extend user profile with no time consuming and very simple coding. Hope, you get it so quickly

Comment: yes i took heavy reference from this website, but it doesn't show any code for saving those newly created profile_picture, dob fields in the custom profile model

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is none need of saving the instance of the profile after saving a User:

```
 @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
  def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

delete above code. To answer your question, if User instance is not created then you don't want to create a profile instance so no need of worrying on that part. Please, add below code to your **admin.py** to have admin User form merged with profile one.

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):    
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'
    fk_name = 'user'
```

Also, would suggest you read on [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/23/how-to-add-user-profile-to-django-admin.html).

You should not get the values directly from the post. This is not a secure way. Either use basic form and get data from `cleaned_data` dictionary or use ModelForm.

I assume you are new in the Django and if you are not too obsessed with using a class-based view, would suggest you use function-based one. It will be easy for you are you will see all the steps.

Follow [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html) one. If not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51371675/7470786) will solve your issue, so you can adjust your code to this one.

Comment: thank you for the improvisations to be made! Could you also provide a solution for saving the fields of Profile model at the time of sign_up def function?

Comment: The simpleisbetterthancomplex website, uses forms for retrieving/saving the data in profile model, however I do not want to make use of forms for this purpose. And the tutorial never shows how location and bio fields are stored in Profile model

Comment: Then how do you plan to retrieve data for sign up? The form is only way even you try to get the values from get and if you want to write them to the database it should be a post request.

Comment: And the link I attached is clearly mentioned the steps of connecting Profile to User.  Not sure what you are talking about.